# Why are my Symfony Router are not Working?

Tags: php, symfony

I am currently creating a Symfony Project for School and i was just trying some things out with this Security Bundle... I was creating the Registration Controller with this `php bin/console make:registration-form` Command and it worked out fine. The Files got created and i got no Errors but when i am trying to go to `/register` they just show me my `index.php` all the time... if i delete index.php its always `# Page not Found` from my Symfony Local Server... Im just testing out so im just using this localhost Webserver from Symfony. I tested out the Route with `php bin/console router:match /register` and it showed green, it works and exists. But when i try going to the Site nothing happens.

```
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Form\RegistrationFormType;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use App\Security\EmailVerifier;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Mime\TemplatedEmail;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Mime\Address;
use Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\Hasher\UserPasswordHasherInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use SymfonyCasts\Bundle\VerifyEmail\Exception\VerifyEmailExceptionInterface;

class RegistrationController extends AbstractController
{
    private EmailVerifier $emailVerifier;

    public function __construct(EmailVerifier $emailVerifier)
    {
        $this->emailVerifier = $emailVerifier;
    }

    #[Route('/register', name: 'app_register')]
    public function register(Request $request, UserPasswordHasherInterface $userPasswordHasher, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
    {
        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm(RegistrationFormType::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            // encode the plain password
            $user->setPassword(
            $userPasswordHasher->hashPassword(
                    $user,
                    $form->get('plainPassword')->getData()
                )
            );

            $entityManager->persist($user);
            $entityManager->flush();

            // generate a signed url and email it to the user
            $this->emailVerifier->sendEmailConfirmation('app_verify_email', $user,
                (new TemplatedEmail())
                    ->from(new Address('info@julian-schaefers.dev', 'Julian Schaefers'))
                    ->to($user->getUserIdentifier())
                    ->subject('Please Confirm your Email')
                    ->htmlTemplate('registration/confirmation_email.html.twig')
            );
            // do anything else you need here, like send an email

            return $this->redirectToRoute('_profiler_home');
        }

        return $this->render('registration/register.html.twig', [
            'registrationForm' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/verify/email', name: 'app_verify_email')]
    public function verifyUserEmail(Request $request, UserRepository $userRepository): Response
    {
        $id = $request->get('id');

        if (null === $id) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_register');
        }

        $user = $userRepository->find($id);

        if (null === $user) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_register');
        }

        // validate email confirmation link, sets User::isVerified=true and persists
        try {
            $this->emailVerifier->handleEmailConfirmation($request, $user);
        } catch (VerifyEmailExceptionInterface $exception) {
            $this->addFlash('verify_email_error', $exception->getReason());

            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_register');
        }

        // @TODO Change the redirect on success and handle or remove the flash message in your templates
        $this->addFlash('success', 'Your email address has been verified.');

        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_register');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, what do you have in services.yaml ?

Comment: `services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true`


`App\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Entity/'
            - '../src/Kernel.php'
            - '../src/Tests/'`

Comment: try to show profiler for the action, and go to routing menu to show what's going on

Comment: Sry.... im new to Symfony xD what do u exactly mean? sorry

Comment: when you are in dev environment, there is a bar in bottom that shows some info.
 Now when you navigate to /register, click on that bar, profiler will open in new tab(it contains all infos about your request), you will find there a menu "Routing", check it to see what exactly was matched

Comment: ah u mean this bar on the website right? it litteraly doesnt exist... anymore. it has existed once but its not there anymore

Comment: Add these 2 lines under access_control in security.yaml
        `
        - { path: /_wdt/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY } 
        - { path: /_profiler/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }`

Comment: Aight what now?

Comment: now you'll be able normally to show the bar and continue debug

Comment: What do you mean "they just show me my index.php"? What is index.php? Are you sure your web-server is configured correctly to forward all URIs to your symfony endpoint?